# Redirect to a page using Friendly URL in liferay

Tags: liferay

I've been searching for quite a long time and i haven't found a solution yet.
I want to know how to redirect to a page using only friendly url from view.

I'm working with Liferay v6.2

**EDIT :**

For example I have a page with friendly url that i know in advance 'domain/users'.
From page A I want to have a link that redirects me to that url.

Comment: A page has a friendly URL. Are you asking how to find the friendly URL of a page, how to redirect in Liferay, how to create your own friendly URL, how to implement navigation on your own in Liferay?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: @OlafKock I've edited my question. I want to redirect in liferay using friendly url that I know instead of using renderURL with action & views.

Comment: you mean like including `<a href="/web/pagename">click here</a>` on your portlet's page?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want. is it possible with liferay?